# Angular2/4 http.get nested access to "this"

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this piece of code

```
 let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': `${this.user.Token}` });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        this.http.get(environment.apiRoot + 'Customers/Customer/Search/' + term + '/' + value, options)
            .map((response) => {
                var Data = response.json().Data;
                return Data;
            }).subscribe(Data => {
                this.data.customer.emailAddress = Data.EmailAddress;
                this.data.customer.phoneNumber = Data.PhoneNumber;
                this.data.customer.firstName = Data.FirstName;
                this.data.customer.lastName = Data.LastName;
                this.data.customer.streetAddress = Data.StreetAddress;
                this.data.customer.city = Data.City;
                this.data.customer.state = Data.State;
                this.data.customer.zipCode = Data.ZipCode;
                this.data.customer.idNumber = Data.IDNumber;
                this.data.customer.ID = Data.ID;
                this.data.customer.comment = Data.Comment;

                // //Check if customer has exsiting orders
                this.http.request(environment.apiRoot + 'Orders/Order/Customer/' + Data.ID, options)
                    .subscribe(odResponse => {
                        var Data = odResponse.json().Data;
                        this.data.orders = Data;
                        this.existingOrders = Data.length > 0;
                    }, error => {
                        this.alertService.error('Encountered an error while trying to get customer order data');
                    });
            }, error => {
                this.alertService.error('Encountered an error while trying to get customer data');
            });
```

The problem I am running into is when the first "GET" is done the "this.data.customer" gets set up, even though in the debugger "this" shows as the the subscribe and not my component, then when the second "GET" executes "this" is the subscribe and saying "this.data.order" is undefined, so is "this.data"

So I guess the question is how do I get "this" in my subscribe to be the component and not the subscribe.

Comment: try this.data['orders'] = Data  . ``this`` here always points to the component as you are using ``=>``

Comment: @krzosik tried that, it did not help at all!

Comment: If you want to chain `Observable`s (doing `http.get` based on the result of another `http.get`), it's better to use `switchMap` rather than `subscribe` inside `subscribe`

Comment: sorry for the confusion guys, it 2 am where I am and I just realized I my endpoint was us running locally and was sitting at a break point when the second get was called! so it never returned anything!  - Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Harry suggested, it is better to use switchMap and do one subscribe call instead of a call in a subcription. In regards to a solution, try this

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': `${this.user.Token}` });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

this.http.get(environment.apiRoot + 'Customers/Customer/Search/' + term + '/' + value, options)
        .map((response) => { // This extracts the data you require
            var Data = response.json().Data;

            return Data;
        }).switchMap(Data => { // This returns the result of the second observable in 
            return this.http.request(environment.apiRoot + 'Orders/Order/Customer/' + Data.ID, options)
                            .map(odResponse => { // We have the response. Extract the json, and return an array with the first element as the old data, and the second element as the new data.
                                 var _Data = odResponse.json().Data;
                                 return [ Data, _Data ];
                             });
        }).subscribe( data => {
            let firstSet = data[0];
            let secondSet = data[1];
            // Now do your assignment 
            this.data.customer.emailAddress = firstSet.EmailAddress;
            this.data.customer.phoneNumber = firstSet.PhoneNumber;
            ...
            ...
        });
```

I've used this approach because it seems that you require the data returned by the first call (the ID) to be able to make the second call. If it was not the case, I would have recommended the use of Observable.forkJoin. [This](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) is the documentation for forkJoin in RxJS V4 but it still applies for V5.

Comment: I ended up using this approach, so I will accept it as the answer! while my original code works this is much cleaner